# ImportError for rqt plugin

Tags: rqt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I want to create a rqt plugin for bagfile comparison called rqt_bag_comparison. Therefore I have followed the tutorial "Create your new rqt plugin", step by step.

When trying to start the plugin from the rqt_gui, I get the following error message:

```
RosPluginProvider.load(rqt_bag_comparison/BagComparisonPlugin) exception raised in __builtin__.__import__(rqt_bag_comparison.bag_comparsion, [BagComparison]):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/groovy/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rqt_gui/ros_plugin_provider.py", line 77, in load
    module = __builtin__.__import__(attributes['module_name'], fromlist=[attributes['class_from_class_type']], level=0)
ImportError: No module named bag_comparsion
```

Apparently, my module is not found. However, in the relative folder to where all my nodes are placed `rqt_bag_comparison/src/rqt_bag_comparison/` there is the file `bag_comparison.py`as well as `__init__.py`.
Is there anything I might have done wrong in the setup, that explains that the module cannot be found?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/188825/importerror-for-rqt-plugin/) by [Kerstin](https://answers.ros.org/users/19928/kerstin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2014-08-04

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From your directory structure containing the `init.py` file `src/rqt_bag_comparison/` your module name would be `rqt_bag_comparison`, not `bag_comparison`.

So I would guess your `plugin.xml` has the wrong setting for `type`. It should be `type="rqt_bag_comparison.bag_comparison.BagComparison"`, if your plugin's class is named `BagComparison` inside `bag_comparison.py`.

---

Originally posted by [Dorian Scholz](https://answers.ros.org/users/485/dorian-scholz/) with karma: 391 on 2014-09-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1